# How to mute all notifications, with some exceptions?

Tags: ios, notifications, do-not-disturb

I have a close friend who's going through a tough time right now, and I want her to be able to wake me up if she needs me. I need to be able to receive push notifications from Messages and Facebook Messenger, but I'd like to be able to mute everything else. Is there a way to do this?

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 9 Public Beta 3, and if it'll help somehow, I also have an early 2011 13" MacBook Pro running El Capitan Public Beta 5.